# How to install PySide for /usr/local/bin/python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside

I am trying to use freeze.py to turn my python script into an executable. However, in order to do this I need to use the source distribution of python3, which gets installed on `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

This is fine except for one thing: My script uses PySide, which was installed (through `sudo apt-get install python3-pyside`) for the system python3 interpreter in `/usr/bin/python3` and not the source distribution python3 in `/usr/local/bin/python3`. So basically I need to find a way to reinstall PySide to the python3 interpreter that I installed from source and not the system python3.

I tried to follow the instructions here http://pyside.readthedocs.org/en/latest/building/linux.html but with no success, as trying to run all the commands using /usr/local/bin/python3 instead of python2 results in a lot of errors. Any ideas how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: what errors did you get, python3 is supported since 1.0.8?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham PySide works with my system python3. Just not with my source distribution python3, which is located in a different directory. I can't find a way to install PySide to be linked to my python3 interpreter in `/usr/local/bin/python3`, `apt-get` installs it to the system python.

Comment: what happened when you tried compiling with /usr/local/bin/python3?

Comment: When I run `/usr/local/bin/python3 get-pip.py`, I get error: `zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available`. I tried running  `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` to fix this but this caused zlib to be installed to the wrong directory again (`/usr/` rather than `/usr/local/`).

Comment: You would need to compile with python with zlib https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1919

Comment: You should also already have pip installed for your /usr/local python, what does `which -a pip3` output?

Comment: I was able to confirm that pip is in `/usr/local/`. However, the step after this requires me to run `/usr/local/bin/python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --qmake=/usr/local/bin/qmake-qt4` (I changed two parts to include the binaries in /usr/local/bin rather than /usr/bin) and I get more errors (`ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'` as well as `ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'` as well as `File '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py --> tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully`. Edit: I also tried to take the /local/ part out of the qmake binary and it still didn't work.

Comment: How did you install the python in /usr/local?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I downloaded it from source (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/) and followed the  instructions in the readme (i.e. make, make install, etc).